# Como criar um relatório no Sql Server com informações por data

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, relatório

Estou criado um sistema para gerenciamento de saída, uma de minhas tabelas guarda as informações de histórico de saídas, ela possui as seguintes colunas,

```
IDpedido,
DataDoPedido
CodProduto,
QuantidadeProduto
CustoProduto (preço de custo)
VendaProduto (preço de venda )
```

como pode ser o meu comando `sql` para que eu possa exibir um relatório de saídas de mercadorias por data?

estou programando em `C#`
usando `Sql Server`

Comment: Que informações você quer exibir e como você quer exibi-las? nós de um exemplo da saída desejada

Comment: Ola, no caso quero exibir data da saida, produto , quantidade , custo , e venda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

João pelo que entendi sua instrução deveria ser:

```
Select DataDoPedido, 
       CodProduto,
       SUM(QuantidadeProduto),
       SUM(CustoProduto), 
       SUM(VendaProduto)
from 
teste GROUP BY DataDoPedido, CodProduto
```

Neste exemplo os dados sairiam agrupados por data e posteriormente por produto.

Fiz um exemplo para ficar mais fácil.
1 º Populei uma tabela com os mesmos campos que a sua:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quanto realizo a consulta que mostrei o resultado é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso fosse necessário selecionar uma data específica bastaria acrescentar a clausula **'WHERE'**

```
Select DataDoPedido, 
       CodProduto,
       SUM(QuantidadeProduto),
       SUM(CustoProduto),
       SUM(VendaProduto)
from teste
Where DataDoPedido = '2018-04-20 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY DataDoPedido, CodProduto
```

Comment: Ola Clayton, mais e no cenário em que o cliente coloca a data que ele quer ?

Comment: João nesse caso bastaria colocar uma clausula 'WHERE' com a data inserida pelo usuário. Ajustei a resposta com esse exemplo também. A diferença é que no seu caso a data não seria fixa, ela teria de ser informada via variável por exemplo, para a instrução SQL

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DataDoPedido, CodProduto, QuantidadeProduto, CustoProduto, VendaProduto
FROM nome_tabela
ORDER BY DataDoPedido;
```